# How to resize a painted object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an outline of a small robot figure. I used the paintbrush tool to colour him in and now I want to be able to resize him. Of course though when I simply resize him, his outline works fine but the paint does not follow (as the outline grows, the paint blobs grow with him but obviously he is not filled so it's not working properly!).

Can someone please help me figure out a way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- Deselect all
- Double click the Scale Tool and make sure **Scale Strokes & Effects** is checked
- Click Ok
- Select the shape and scale it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually just discovered Object > Expand Appearance so that's how it's done. Now the fill is done as a normal fill would be rather than paintbrush and now I can resize as needed!

Comment: Actually.. Daniellilo's method is *much* better than expanding in many instances.